# Сделать коммит в другую ветку

Tags: git

У меня есть две ветки: `dev` и `fix`. Я, будучи на ветке `fix`, сделал некоторую работу локально. Но я хочу закоммитить изменения в ветку `dev`.
После попытки `git checkout dev` я получаю ошибку

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

Я пытался пойти путем

```
git stash
git checkout dev
git stash pop
```

Но на этапе `git checkout dev` получаю ошибку

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>           public/favicon.ico

(я заменил favicon в проекте, но в коммит это изменение попало как `delete favicon.ico`, т. к. название файла то же, но ранее файл был пустым, а я заменил его на иконку).
Как сделать коммит в другую ветку и как разобраться с favicon?

---

**UPDATE:** По совету [alexander barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin) убрал favicon.ico с рабочего каталога, потом проделал

```
git stash
git checkout dev
git stash pop
```

и вернул favicon.ico обратно.

Comment: переместите файл куда-нибудь за пределы рабочего каталога, а после `stash pop` верните обратно